# Export Product Catalog from Personalization (formerly Interaction Studio) into a DE in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

SF support have said the ability to export the entire Catalog is a product limitation they are aware of and it is on the roadmap for a future feature release but cannot provide timelines.

Has anyone been able to implement any workarounds to export a dataset's Product Catalog from Personalization (formerly Interaction Studio) into a Data Extension in Marketing Cloud?

Currently the manual export function on the Product page does not satisfy our needs. We need to be able to have all attributes for all Products and have it exported on a recurring basis.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

as Support mentioned, there isn't a programmatic way to export catalogue data yet, but there's an unofficial workaround that might help you.

It is very well explained in this Mateusz's article: https://mateuszdabrowski.pl/docs/interaction-studio/is-catalog-architecture/#export-full-is-catalog-data

He also created a Salesforce Idea for this solution to be implemented. You might want to consider upvoting it here: https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000NVRj3UAH/full-is-mcp-catalog-export

Comment: Many thanks, I found this as well but we need an automated, recurring job, which unfortunately doesn't seem possible at the moment.